# I can't go to the other paths i am using flask

Tags: python, flask

I am studying [this course](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:HarvardX+CS50W+Web/courseware/3b4d945d89eb40bcad81746770a81c3b/c62f675bf7f94f0e91b408cacda56451/?child=first) on flask. This is the basic flask code. When I am on the first route I am fine but when I try to put slash and got for another page it doesn't work.

I get this message:

> "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."

I did run `FLASK_APP=app.py flask run`
after saving.

```py
from Flask import flask

app= Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def index():
    return "index"
@app.route('/me')

def me():
    return "me"

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In class it works well. When i do it it does not

```
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jul/2019 02:43:55] "GET /me/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I'm guessing 404 at the end is problem

After the reply

```
from Flask import flask

app= Flask(__name__)
strict_slashes=False

@app.route('/')

def index():
    return "index"
@app.route('/me/')

def me():
    return "me"

if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your "/me" route explicitly without trailing slash. However, when calling the URL, you are calling it with slash in the end "/me/". Werkzeug (Flask development application server) by default has the rule of "strict_slashes=True", which requires you to follow exact route declaration when calling your URLs. In other words, if in your code, you declared "@app.route('/me'), your should call "127.0.0.1/me", not "127.0.0.1/me/".

Removing the slash in the end (e.g. http://localhost/me) will fix your issue. You can also change the Werkzeug setting and set strict_slashes=False if you want to remove the default rule.

Comment: I tried the above(edited) it still does not work. I am new to flask so could you tell  a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I would say make a app.errorhandler(404) and then define what to do after you get an error to check if it is a 404 error, and other errors. I would also say use html and make links which you can use to go into different pages, it is easier than typing manually. here is my code:

python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
app.route('/')
def home():
  return render_template('home.html')
app.route('/me')
def me():
  return 'me'
app.errorhandler(404)
  def error(arg):
        return 'wrong url'
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

html:

```
<!-- you can use css to make the link look better or <style> </style>-->
<a href="/me"></a>
```